# Lock MacBook without sleeping LAN?

Tags: macbook-pro, network

On Macbook pro 2019 and Catalina, when I lock the screen and come back even within 10 minutes, I have to wait while DHCP gets another IP lease. It's usually the same IP. But that takes up to 60 seconds. However, on my Windows laptop, the LAN is available immediately. What could be going on with the Macbook? My coworker has same Macbook Pro, same docking station, and does not have this issue.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchlp1168/10.14/mac/10.14.5 Try turning on Power nap.